# Responsive media queries

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media, responsive

Im very confused at the moment, so im trying to create a responsive website.

For some reason my media queries are not triggering? I have the below CSS and it works fine from X-Small Below 480px and up to 575.98px. but past the media query, anything that I add into the 767.98px range isnt working at all?

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
    .card-4{
        display: none;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
    #about{
        padding: 0 0.5rem 0 0.5rem;
    }
    .about-photo img{
        width: 70%;
    }
    .about-text{
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1rem 0 3rem 0;
    }
    .about-text h1, .about-text p{
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
    }
    .table{
        margin: 0;  
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    .table li{
        margin: auto;
        padding-top: 0.3rem;
        padding-left: 2rem;
        text-align: left;   
    }
    #skills-list{
        margin: 0 2rem 0 2rem;
    }
    #skills-list li{
        text-align: left;
        padding-bottom: 1rem;   
    }
    .card-1{
        display: none;
    }
    .card{
        margin-left: auto !important; 
        margin-right: auto !important;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .cards-container{
        margin: 0 !important;
    }
    .timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
    width: 85%;
    float: right;
    padding: 1.2rem;
}
    .timeline:before {
    left: 6%;
}
    .timeline > li > .timeline-badge {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    left: 6%;
}
.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:before {
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-right-width: 15px;
    left: -15px;
    right: auto;
}
.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-right-width: 14px;
    left: -14px;
    right: auto;
}
.square-1-text, .square-2-text, .square-3-text{
    height: 31rem;
}
.square-1{
    order:1;
}
.square-1-text{
    order:2;
}
.square-2{
    order:3;
}
.square-2-text{
    order:4;
}
#passions-section{  
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
#skills-list li.i{
        list-style-position: outside !important;
        display: none;
    }
/*// Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)*/
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    }

/*// Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px)*/
@media (max-width: 991.98px) {

}

/*// Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px)*/
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {

}
```

Comment: What is not working exactly? I made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sprkx2o/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the right breakpoints in your CSS media queries is likely the most important decision when implementing a fully responsive site.

Min-width: 320px (smaller phone viewpoints)
Min-width: 480px (small devices and most phones)
Min-width: 768px (most tablets)
Min-width: 992px (smaller desktop viewpoints)
Min-width: 1200px (large devices and wide screens)

In your case Try this one

```
@media (min-width:500px) and (max-width:750px)
```

Comment: ahhh thank you, I am going to tick your answer as it has resolved my issue, but would you kindly mind explaining the difference between min/max-width because i never know which to use and why.

Comment: `max` = everything **below** the amount - `min` everything **above** the amount

Comment: is it better to use Min over max? if so why?

Comment: It used to target specific devices with known widths.